# Prove that there is a subgroup of index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $N \lhd G$ so that $[G:N]=2014$.
I need to prove that there is a subgroup of index 2.

Indeed, since $N \lhd G$, $o(G/N)=2014$, but I  couldn't find how to go on.

Comment: sounds interesting... could you tell the background for this question? some theorems/lemmas that you can use?

Comment: I think that Sylow Theorems might be in use, but I'm not sure...

Comment: A subgroup of $G$ or $G/N$?

Comment: More generally, any group of twice odd order has a subgroup of index $2$: take the intersection of the regular permutation representation with the alternating group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work in $G/N$:

We have $2014=2\times 19\times 53$.

Hence there exist a subgroup of order $53$. This subgroup is either normal, or there would be at least $54$ such subgroup. Since $53$ is a prime, any 2 subgroup of order $53$ must intersect only at $e$. So there cannot be $54$ subgroup of order $53$. Thus the subgroup of order $53$ is a normal subgroup $H$. Hence we quotient that one out again. And the rest is easy.

Then the rest is just standard correspondence theorem.

Comment: Maybe you meant that there would be at least 38 such subgroup (instead of 54)?

Comment: I'm not sure where the $38$ come from, but no: $38\not\equiv 1(\mod 53)$

Comment: I have 1 normal subgroup of order 53, and 1 normal subgroup of order 19.  I'm not sure how to go on..

Comment: If both group are normal, then just take their product. (actually, you just need 1 normal group)

Comment: Can you please explain more how to go on?

Comment: Let's say $H$ and $K$ is the group of order $53$ and $19$, in which $H$ is normal. Then $HK$ is a group, and since $H$ and $K$ only intersect at $e$ the order is $53\times 19$. That's one way. Or you can just take the quotient $(G/N)/H$ and find another subgroup in that and then apply correspondence twice. You might want to add in to your question exactly how far have you got in group theory, because it's possible that you still got stuck because people are referring to theorem you have not learnt.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the Sylow-Theorems to show that the group $G/N$ of order $2014=2\cdot 19 \cdot 53$ has a subgroup $H/N$ of index $2$. Then use the Correspondence Theorem to conclude that this corresponds to $H<G$ with $(G:H)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, we can just replace $G$ with $G/N$, and assume that $G$ itself has order 2014.

We have $2014 = 2 \times 19 \times 53$.

The number of $53$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ divides $2 \times 19 = 38$, but at the same time is congruent to $1 \mod 53$. So there is only one subgroup of $G$ of order 53. Therefore that subgroup is normal. (Any conjugate of it can only be itself.)

So modding out by that subgroup, we can now assume that $G$ has order 38. A $19$-Sylow subgroup will do the trick.

Comment: This is the same as Gina's answer. How do I delete mine?